# DialogFlow Twitter Rich Message Card

Tags: twitter, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Does anyone have an example of some DialogFlow Response that will send something other than text to Twitter? I'm using the new integration through GCP. Any sort of "Hello World" showing a Card, Suggestion, anything more that text. We tried Custom Response and Fulfillment .js code and have not been able to render anything.

Comment: What do you mean by a card or a suggestion - can you provide example Tweets that you're trying to replicate somehow? When you say "new implementation", is this different to the one that shuts down in May? https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/twitter

Comment: Ideally a Card Message object because it has a postback text. https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/message-objects#card_message_object  The built-in Twitter integration is deprecated in favor of an open source integration.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twitter

Comment: That documentation does not show Twitter as an option for a Card message object, what sort of existing Tweet do you want to create?